# database-based content management system design

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i'm looking for best practise on designing database schema for content management system. any reference on this?

p/s: i do not plan to use open source lib. as i need to get it work on google app engine + JAVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I just read a review for a book about CMS design.

Review:

http://www.digitalsandwich.com/archives/76-Book-Review-PHP5-CMS-Framework-Development-by-Martin-Brampton.html

Amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/PHP-CMS-Framework-Development-management/dp/1847193579](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847193579)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have to warn you, the App Engine datastore is very different from a relational database like MySQL.  Trying to use the datastore like a relational database will be very inefficient, or downright impossible.  And it won't teach you anything about relational databases, which seems to be your goal.